# Sum multiple BigDecimals to a Map<String, BigDecimal>

Tags: java, sum, java-stream, bigdecimal

I'm trying to sum multiple BigDecimals from a `List`. Currently, I'm using two streams, but would like to have only one stream if possible. I'm unsure how I can rewrite below in a performant way.

```
BigDecimal totalCharges = tableRowDataList.stream()
            .map(el -> el.getSums().getCharges())
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal totalFees = tableRowDataList.stream()
            .map(el -> el.getSums().getFees())
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

As you can see, the streams are doing basically the same, only the call to getCharges/getFees differ.

What is the best way to get a resulting `Map<String, BigDecimal>` from above? (Where key would be charges/fees)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you create a class for collecting the result.

You then do the same as BigDecimal has, i.e. a `ZERO` constant and an `add()` method.

```
public class ChargesAndFees {
    private static final ZERO = new ChargesAndFees(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO);

    private final BigDecimal charges;
    private final BigDecimal fees;

    // constructor and getters

    public ChargesAndFees add(ChargesAndFees that) {
        return new ChargesAndFees(this.charges.add(that.charges),
                                  this.fees.add(that.fees));
    }
}
```

Now you can do the stream logic

```
ChargesAndFees totals = tableRowDataList.stream()
        .map(el -> new ChargesAndFees(el.getSums().getCharges(),
                                      el.getSums().getFees()))
        .reduce(ChargesAndFees.ZERO, ChargesAndFees::add);
```

If you insist, you can then convert the values in `totals` into a `Map`.

Comment: I was writing the exact same thing. This case needs a class devoted to handle the sum. I think the `ChargesAndFees` class could use a `toMap` method to validate OP's requirement.

Comment: @JeremyGrand My take is that request for `Map` was an XY Problem, but I did add that "If you insist" at the end, and OP should be able to write that, if needed.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas! The Map was indeed an XY Problem, now that I see your approach...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of objects List<TableRowDataElement>, each of which has a Sums object-- do you control the definition of TableRowDataElement and/or Sums?

If you create an add method in either TableRowDataElement or Sums, then you can simplify this without the need for an additional class--

```
Sums sums = tableRowDataList.stream()
        .map(el -> el.getSums())
        .reduce(new Sums(0,0), Sums::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
Optional<Entry<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>> res = StreamEx.of(tableRowDataList)
            .map(e -> e.getSums())
            .mapToEntry(s -> s.getCharges(), s -> s.getFees())
            .reduce((a, b) -> {
                a.getKey().add(b.getKey());
                b.getKey().add(b.getValue());
                return a;
            });
```

I think we should try to avoid creating those tiny helper classes. Otherwise, you will run into the trouble of maintaining tens/hundreds tiny classes.